# Building (sub)project generated by swagger-codegen gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, swagger-codegen

I'm using some sort of gradle task chain to download a swagger.yaml, generate code utilizing [Gradle Swagger Gernerator Plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin), create a .jar file out of that generated code and then upload it to private Nexus server.

At least, that's what I'd live to do. If the generated code does not exist, the whole chain fails.

I have a custom tasks chaining them all together, which looks like this:

```
task generate(type: GradleBuild) {
     tasks = ['downloadFile', 'generateSwaggerCode', ':subProject:jar', 'upload']
}
```

`generateSwaggerCode` generates the code in to "subProject" which is included using the "settings.gradle": `include subProject`. That way, I can run gradle tasks of a subproject. This is needed to make sure gradle also downloads dependencies of the sub project. The [gradle plugin's readme](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin#build-generated-code) states one can build the project right from the root's gradle task by hooking into the compileJava task which fails due to missing dependencies of the just generated code.

Everything seems to work well while calling `generateSwaggerCode` beforehand thus the "subProject" already exist.

I'm looking for a way to either ignore the check, or call the generated code's gradle wrapper otherwise without calling two seperate tasks in a row.